# Onhoverlistener does not work in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, onhover

I am working in android studio (my phone Android 6.0.1 api 23) on an app, which 
should play sound on hover on, stop playing on release. It is not working. Is it because of my hardware? Or my code is wrong?

**JAVA:**

```
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public class DisplayActivity  extends AppCompatActivity {

    private MediaPlayer player;

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();


        player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.cena);


        player.setLooping(true);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();


        player.release();
        player = null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        findViewById(R.id.hello).setOnHoverListener(new View.OnHoverListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onHover(
                    View v,
                    MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_HOVER_ENTER:
                        player.start();
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_HOVER_EXIT:
                        player.pause();
                        player.seekTo(0);
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
}
```

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.android.testonhover.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/hello"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hover me!"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Could you explain me what should I do to make it work?

Comment: Which pointing device are you using to _hover_?

Comment: The purpose is to use finger

Comment: And hover using finger? I believe there are [very few devices](http://www.gsmarena.com/sony_xperia_sola-4408.php) that are able to do that. Are you sure you don't want to play/stop on touch?

Comment: @SlashG I want my app to work similar to a **guitar app**. There would be several buttons (or TextViews) which should be playing sounds (each button has its own sound) when I "swipe" them over with my finger, without releasing it.
Can it be done with play/stop on touch or should i use something else?

Comment: Oh, that is one interesting idea. Also, hover isn't an event that you need to listen to. Have you heard of raycasting? We can continue this discussion in a conversation.

Comment: Sure, let's move the topic to the converstion @SlashG

Comment: Funny that I can't find an option to do that. Any clue?

Comment: I have an option to move this conversation to chat, but i do not have enough reputation :( I need 11 more

Comment: I can give you a basic idea here. But it would be best if we moved this to a conversation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126527/discussion-between-rediner-and-slashg).